# How to upload folders into my github repository?

Tags: github

I want to upload a folder which contains another folder inside of it. When i tried dragging folder, it says that "something went really wrong, and we can't proccess that file.".[image]

How do i upload my folders to GitHub?

Comment: what is there in console?

Comment: I tried to upload 3 files and 2 folders. I wanted so that my folders also appears on the repository.

Comment: I checked now on github. No issues I found. I am able to upload folders with subfolders and files in it. So, what is the error you getting in console

Answer (score 4):

Uploading folders from most browsers is a pain. Only Chrome seems to have some implementation that works sometimes.

Instead, you should clone the repository to your computer and add the folder in the repository. Then, you run `git add folder/*`, `git commit -m "<Message Here>"` and `git push origin master`. This will add all the files in the folder to your repository, commit them and push them, effectively uploading a new folder to your repository.

Answer (score -1):

```
git init
git add (folder_name) "eg.git add assets
git commit -m "message"
git remote add orgin (github repository url)
git push -u orgin master
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).